# In Android Studio, how to flag dependencies with old versions when specified from buildSrc Dependenices kotlin file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies.kt` file with dependencies such as

```
object Deps {
    const val lifecycleVersion = "2.6.2"

    const val lifecycle = listOf(
        "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion",
        "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycleVersion"
    )
}
```

And in module build.gradle.kts I have

```
dependencies {
    ...
    Deps.lifecycle.forEach(::implementation)
    ...
}
```

If I specific the dependency directly in the module build.gradle.kts, like,

```
val lifecycleVersion = "2.6.2"
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion")
```

[image]

Android Studio will warn if there are newer version available. However, it won't be the case if I use dependencies from buildSrc plugin. How to add the "dependency inspection" (effectively) to `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies.kt` or at least indicate in the module gradle file that there are newer versions available?

Is there a plugin that can resolve the values listed in Dependencies.kt and flag appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use version catalogs to keep all dependencies and their versions in one central place, alerting you if there is a newer version for some dependency.

a version catalogs belongs to a `settings.gradle` file and automatically added to your project if you use the default name (read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)) so all other gradle modules can access the same file with no further work. but if you want to access it from buildSrc (which has its own settings.gradle file) add this to `buildSrc/settings.gradle` file

```kotlin
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            from(files("../gradle/libs.versions.toml"))
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You can use build-logic instead of buildSrc to create convention plugins that can share your build logic for your modules. Another benefit of build-logic is that if you change it, gradle won't invalidate your project cache (which happens in buildSrc).